# comparing string to an NSMutable array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

another quick question. how to compare an string with the values of an array
for example

```
string a =@"abc";

compare = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"abc",@"d",nil]];
```

if string matches any of the element in array, i should show some alert or something.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ([compare containsObject:a]) {
   // show alert;
}
```

If that array will become arbitrarily long, it's better to use an NSSet instead.